# In Rails, how do you generate the show view from an existing model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say you already have a model, but want to generate the show view that would normally be generated as if you generated that model via a scaffold.  Is there a generator you can invoke to generate a show view from an existing model?

The command would look like:

```
rails g show_view User
```

I'd also want this to pick up the properties from my existing model and write them as fields into the views.

Comment: For a list of available generators: `rails generate -h`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to use `scaffold_controller`

```
$ rails g scaffold_controller User
```

More info about `scaffold_controller`

> Stubs out a scaffolded controller and its views. Pass the model name, either >CamelCased or under_scored, and a list of views as arguments. The controller name is >retrieved as a pluralized version of
>   the model name.To create a controller within a module, specify the model name as a path like 'parent_module/controller_name'.
>
> ```
> This generates a controller class in app/controllers and invokes helper, template engine and test framework generators.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good first step.  This doesnt seem to pick up the properties on the model and write as fields into the views.  How can I get it to do that, or is that even possible?

Comment: Not possible using default generators. however, you can create your own generator to do this. see [Creating and Customizing Rails Generators & Templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html)